# URDF Transmissions

Tags: urdf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have a question about using the  tag in the URDF file. Link: URDF Transmissions

What is your purpose? Should I use it in the URDF file of my real robot? Or should I use it for simulation with Gazebo only

I'm using ROS Kinetics

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336244/urdf-transmissions/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Transmission in the field of robotics consists of gear trains, actuators and shafts coupled with the robot links. This allows the transmission to have a desired control of the robot links.  Based on the existing motors and the gear trains we will be able to define the resulting link motion.

You can follow this [link](https://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/Transmission) for the description on transmission. Transmission can be used in real robot as well as in gazebo. For gazebo, currently, there is only simple transmission available. Hopefully in future, we have it for differential transmission (example: PR2 wrist) as well.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) with karma: 224 on 2019-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2